# Translate to image in jCanvascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, jcanvascript

I apply jcanvaScript (JavaScript library)

on the canvas element there are some images how it is possible to trade places images (after a click a mouse for example)?

```
    function start(){   

// Add mouse listener.
canvas = document.getElementById('firstCanvas');

canvas.addEventListener('click',coordinateClick);

    var img =[];
    for(var i=0;i<16;i++){
    img[i]=new Image;
    img[i].src="./image/"+i+".png";
    }

    jc.start('firstCanvas',true);

        function allOnloadImages(){//initialization by canvas id


            for(var i=0;i<16;i++){

            jc.image(img[i],cordinaImg[i][0],cordinaImg[i][1]).id('img'+i);

            };              

    };              

    jc.start('firstCanvas');

    for(var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
        img[i].onload=allOnloadImages;          
    }

}
function coordinateClick(e){

 ...    
//here we interchange the position of pictures 


    jc('#img'+i).translateTo(cordinaImg[numberFieldEmpty][0],cordinaImg[numberFieldEmpty][1]+11);
 jc('#img15').translateTo(cordinaImg[i][0],cordinaImg[i][1]+11);
...

    }
```

Thus there is a bifurcating of pictures, that is two copies of the same picture...
for example if so 
won't remove anything

```
jc('#img'+i).del();//
```